# How to append items to nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an outer JS array 'main_category' which should contain several arrays within it called 'temp'.

The array temp contains several string elements taken from an li tag.

In order to populate both the arrays I am running a for-loop through each li tag for each ul tag in the html page, as shown below:

```
function a{
   var category_list = [];
   var temp;

   //how to split this list iteration into two for-loops
   $(".ul_list li").each(function(){
       temp = [];
       //adding only those list elements of a ul, that are red in color
       if($(this).attr("style") == "color:red"){
          var cat = $(this).text();
          cat = cat.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '); //removes whitespaces
          temp.push(cat); //creates a single array for a single element
       }
    }
    category_list.push(temp);  
   });
 }
```

**Desired output**:

```
  category_list = [['l1', 'l2', 'l3'], ['l1', 'l2', 'l3'], ['l1', 'l2', 'l3']..]
```

**Current output**:

```
   category_list = [['li'], ['l2'], ['l3']...]
```

However, the temp.push(cat) LOC creates a temp array for each individual li element instead of creating a temp=[] for all the li elements within one ul.

Comment: Are there multiple `.ul_list`?  Also it looks like an invalid function definition for `function a(){}`

Comment: You push `temp` to the category array  in a scope where `temp` is not defined. The expression `category_list.push(temp)` needs to be moved one line up.

Comment: @Taplar yes there are 12-15 .ul_list in the html template. No the function is being invoked successfully on the button click

Comment: The `.ul_list li` will select a flat list of `<li>` elements. The elements will not get magically grouped by their parent `<ul>` element.

Comment: Can you provide sample of input and desired output, as well as the output that you are actually getting?

Comment: @plalx that's exactly what I am asking, I am unable to group together the list items for one list, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through iterating through each `.ul_list` element then their children in that order should give you the expected result.

```js
function a() {
 let list = []
 $(".ul_list").each(function() {
  let temp = []
  $(this).children().each(function() {
   let text = $(this).text()
   text.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')
   temp.push(text)
  })
  list.push(temp)
 })
 return list
}

console.log(a())
```

Or if you need a recursive implementation that can handle nested `ul`s inside of each other:

```js
function getListItems(ul) {
  let temp = []
  $(ul).children().each(function() {
    if ($(this).is("ul")) { // checks if child is a list 
      temp.push(getListItems($(this))) // recursive call
    } else { // child is list item
      let text = $(this).text()
      text.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')
      temp.push(text)
    }
  })
  return temp
}


function a() { // main function
  let list = []
  $(".ul_list").each(function() {
    list.push(getListItems($(this)))
  })
  return list
}

console.log(a())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="ul_list">
    <li>l1</li>
    <li>l2</li>
    <li>l3</li>
    <ul>
      <li>l1</li>
      <li>l2</li>
      <li>l3</li>
      <ul>
        <li>l1</li>
        <li>l2</li>
        <li>l3</li>
        <ul>
          <li>l1</li>
          <li>l2</li>
          <li>l3</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul_list">
    <li>l1</li>
    <li>l2</li>
    <li>l3</li>
    <ul>
      <li>l1</li>
      <li>l2</li>
      <li>l3</li>
      <ul>
        <li>l1</li>
        <li>l2</li>
        <li>l3</li>
        <ul>
          <li>l1</li>
          <li>l2</li>
          <li>l3</li>
          <ul>
            <li>l1</li>
            <li>l2</li>
            <li>l3</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul_list">
    <li>l1</li>
    <li>l2</li>
    <li>l3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul_list">
    <li>l1</li>
    <li>l2</li>
    <li>l3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul_list">
    <li>l1</li>
    <li>l2</li>
    <li>l3</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will map each ul to an array, and all the lis in each ul to an array, so it will be a 2 dimensional array, where each `category_list[#]` is a ul and the sub array is each li's text you modified.

```js
function a() {
  var category_list = $('.ul_list').get().map(function(ul){
    return $('li', ul).get().map(function(li){
      return $(li).text().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '); //removes whitespaces
    });
  });
  
  console.log(category_list);
}

a();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="ul_list">
  <li>1 Thing</li>
  <li>2 Thing</li>
  <li>3 Thing</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul_list">
  <li>4 Thing</li>
  <li>5 Thing</li>
  <li>6 Thing</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This code is only creating an array with all li elements within it. It is not creating a sub-array for li elements belonging to one particular ul

Comment: The outer map is on the ul.  The inner map is on the li's for the ul.  You're saying this is not working? @Simran

Comment: Yes its creating a single Array(45) of 45 elements, i.e for a total of 5 list items * 9 lists

Comment: Weird, for some reason it was flattening it.  Modified it, and included a runnable snippet to show it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit over simplified but I got the desired output.
https://jsbin.com/tofimik/edit?html,js,console,output
Step 1. declare empty array
Step 2. run your loop, get all children in your `ul` element
 
Step 3. Turn each collection of children into an array
Step 4. Push child collection into new array

```
  var temp = []
  var cat;
  $('ul').each(function(){
    cat = []
    var liTags = Array($(this).children().text().trim());
    temp.push(liTags);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author)*.

This solution was provided by James_F:

```
   function a{
     let category_list = [];

     $(".ul_list").each(function(){
       let temp = [];
       $(this).children().each(function(){
          //adding only those list elements of a ul, that are red in color
          if($(this).children().attr("style") == "color:red"){
             var cat = $(this).text();
             cat = cat.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '); //removes whitespaces
             temp.push(cat); //creates a single array for a single element
          }
       })
       category_list.push(temp);
     })
   }
```